# aggregation and subsets in r - calculate the number of hours that actors worked together in the past

Tags: r

I am using a large dataset of employees that have collaborated on certain projects. The data is structured like this (sorry about the headers!):

```
            Project Person_i Person_j Year Hours_ij
            101 ID1 ID4 2009    20
            101 ID2 ID5 2009    30
            101 ID3 ID6 2009    40
            102 ID1 ID4 2010    20
            102 ID2 ID5 2010    30
            102 ID3 ID6 2010    40
            103 ID1 ID4 2011    20
            103 ID2 ID5 2011    30
            103 ID3 ID6 2011    40
            104 ID1 ID4 2012    20
            104 ID2 ID5 2012    30
            104 ID3 ID6 2012    40
```

I want to calculate the number of hours that two persons (i.e., unique combinations of "Person_i" and "Person_j") have collaborated in prior projects. Below is an example of the desired data. Here, the variable "Prior_hours" is the sum of "Hours_ij" in prior observations of the variable "Year":

```
            Project Person_i    Person_j    Year    Hours_ij    Prior_hours
            101 ID1 ID4 2009    20  0
            101 ID2 ID5 2009    30  0
            101 ID3 ID6 2009    40  0
            102 ID1 ID4 2010    20  20
            102 ID2 ID5 2010    30  30
            102 ID3 ID6 2010    40  40
            103 ID1 ID4 2011    20  40
            103 ID2 ID5 2011    30  60
            103 ID3 ID6 2011    40  80
            104 ID1 ID4 2012    20  60
            104 ID2 ID5 2012    30  90
            104 ID3 ID6 2012    40  120
```

I have tried to split and aggregate the file (with subsets), but I just can't figure this out. Your time and help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with your example:

```
df <- read.table(text="Project Person_i Person_j Year Hours_ij
101 ID1 ID4 2009 20
101 ID2 ID5 2009 30
101 ID3 ID6 2009 40
102 ID1 ID4 2010 20
102 ID2 ID5 2010 30
102 ID3 ID6 2010 40
103 ID1 ID4 2011 20
103 ID2 ID5 2011 30
103 ID3 ID6 2011 40
104 ID1 ID4 2012 20
104 ID2 ID5 2012 30
104 ID3 ID6 2012 40", sep=" ", header=T)

df$Prior_hours <- unsplit(
     tapply(df$Hours_ij, 
            paste(df$Person_i, df$Person_j), 
            function(x) c(0,cumsum(x[1:length(x)-1]))),
     paste(df$Person_i, df$Person_j))

df
   Project Person_i Person_j Year Hours_ij Prior_hours
1      101      ID1      ID4 2009       20           0
2      101      ID2      ID5 2009       30           0
3      101      ID3      ID6 2009       40           0
4      102      ID1      ID4 2010       20          20
5      102      ID2      ID5 2010       30          30
6      102      ID3      ID6 2010       40          40
7      103      ID1      ID4 2011       20          40
8      103      ID2      ID5 2011       30          60
9      103      ID3      ID6 2011       40          80
10     104      ID1      ID4 2012       20          60
11     104      ID2      ID5 2012       30          90
12     104      ID3      ID6 2012       40         120
```